# ES6 map an array of objects, to return an array of objects with new keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bill'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ted'
    }
]
```

Looking for a simple one-liner to return:

```
[
    {
        value: 1,
        text: 'bill'
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        text: 'ted'
    }
]
```

So I can easily pump them into a react dropdown with the proper keys.

I feel like this simple solution should work, but I'm getting invalid syntax errors:

```
this.props.people.map(person => { value: person.id, text: person.name })
```

Comment: You need `person => ({...`. In other words, enclose the object literal in parens. Otherwise JS thinks it's the beginning of a block.

Answer (score 739):

You just need to wrap object in `()`

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'bill'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'ted'
}]

var result = arr.map(person => ({ value: person.id, text: person.name }));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand why the parentheses are necessary, but they do indeed work.   When using JSX, If I keep the tag on the same line, parentheses aren't required, so I guess I figured the same would be for an object on the same line.

Comment: Ah, from the post that this is apparently a duplicate of: "Otherwise curly braces will be considered to denote the function’s body." That makes sense now. Thanks again.

Comment: This will work too, but it is essentially just a different way to write the code, I added this because the OP did not understand the parenthesis, and I ran across this thread while solving an issue myself: var result = arr.map((person)=>{ 
return {value:person.id, text:person.name };
});

Comment: If don't want to add the parenthesis then instead of ":" use "=". this.props.people.map(person => { value= person.id, text= person.name })

Comment: @NitinAgarwal: Are you sure? Your suggestion does not work for me. And it makes sense, that it doesn't. I get an error saying that "value" and "text" are not declared.

Comment: can we make the key to be dynamic here ? for e.g some property from inside Person