# map array to another array in TypeScript

Tags: reactive

Can I improve my code and replace for-loop by array.map?

I searched and I think I could do that but I didn't find how could I apply that.

This is what I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348171/es6-map-an-array-of-objects-to-return-an-array-of-objects-with-new-keys) :

```
var result = arr.map(person => ({ value: person.id, text: person.name }));
```

And my code is here:

```
  public getFlights(): Observable<RowItem[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiHostFlights)
      .map((res: any) => {
        return <LocationModelItem[]>res.json();
      })
      .map((items: LocationModelItem[]) => {
        var rowItems: RowItem[]=[];
        var cachedLenght = items.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < cachedLenght; i++) {
          rowItems.push(
            new RowItem(i, items[i].name, items[i].img, items[i].category)
          );
        }
        return rowItems;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 public getFlights(): Observable<RowItem[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiHostFlights)
      .map((res: any) => {
        return <LocationModelItem[]>res.json();
      })
      .map((items: LocationModelItem[]) => {
        return items.map((item, index) => ({
           index: index,
           name: item.name,
           img: item.img,
           category: item.category)
        }))

      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
      });
  }
```

This should do it hopefully

Comment: can I you made it like this answer var result = arr.map(person => ({ value: person.id, text: person.name }));

Comment: That means you want to get a list of objects instead of a list of RowItems?

Comment: I just want a better performance instead of using for loop or 3 maps but rowitems

Comment: still I loop 3 times by using 3 maps

Comment: Because you have to. I see no logical possibility to avoid that.

Comment: @amorenew and "3 maps" is a problem because... ?

Comment: As I understand map is like for loop so it is a performance issue