# React.js - this.props.children an object when spreading the result of a .map from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

I am having some strange behaviour where `this.props.children` is converting to an object when I spread the result of a `.map()` from the parent.

**example:**

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "Name1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Name2" }
].map((item) => {
  return (
    <DropdownMenu_listItem key={item.id} item={item} />
  );
});

render() {
  return (
    <DropdownMenu
      label={'Some label'}
      onChange={() => {}}
    >
      {...items}
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

// DropdownMenu.js

render() {
  console.log(this.props.children); // {0: {…}, 1: {…}}

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

The weird part is that when I omit the `.map()` and pass the elements directly, they appear in `this.props.children` as an array like expected:

```
render() {
  return (
    <DropdownMenu
      label={'Some label'}
      onChange={() => {}}
    >
      <DropdownMenu_listItem item={{...}} />
      <DropdownMenu_listItem item={{...}} />
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

// DropdownMenu.js

render() {
  console.log(this.props.children); // [{…}, {…}]

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason behind this decision?

Comment: check this answer, it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348171/es6-map-an-array-of-objects-to-return-an-array-of-objects-with-new-keys

Answer (score 7):

Its not because of map that you get children as object, but because you use spread operator for the items in

```
<DropdownMenu
          label={'Some label'}
          onChange={() => {}}
        >
          {...items} {/*spread operator here */}
</DropdownMenu>
```

Now that after map items is an array using `{...items }` makes it an object since you wrap your result of spread operator with `{}`, If you write `{items}`, that will be fine

```
 <DropdownMenu
      label={'Some label'}
      onChange={() => {}}
    >
      {items}
 </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: But OP mentioned that if he removes the `map` functionality then he is getting the array. As per your answer both the cases he should get object. is that correct?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai In the second case he is manually adding `<DropdownMenu_listItem item={{...}} />
      <DropdownMenu_listItem item={{...}} />` as children and not using spread operator

Answer (score 7):

`{...items}` is passed as childrens in `DropdownMenu.js`.

Its available as a `this.props.children`

`this.props.children` can be array or object depend on how you rendering the children elements.

in your case

```
<DropdownMenu
      label={'Some label'}
      onChange={() => {}}
    >
      {...items}
</DropdownMenu>
```

items is an array. As we know

```
array is also type of object in javascript

with key equal to element's index and value is element itself
```

`{...items}` : this will passed as a object with key as a element index and value equal to array element.

To fix your problem, you should passed it without using spread operator.

`{items}` : this will passed as an array.

```
<DropdownMenu
      label={'Some label'}
      onChange={() => {}}
    >
      {items}
</DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: I was previously using { ...children } which didn't work so, I used { this.props.children } and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

In my case passing as attr will worked

before

```
function Foo(props) {
    return <Bar> {...props} </Bar>
}
```

after

```
function Foo(props) {
    return <Bar {...props}> </Bar>
}
```