# Best way to replace key of array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my array:

```
data = [{"src": 'a'},
        {'src': 'b'},
        {'src': 'c'}];
```

But I want to change key like this:

```
data = [{"letter": 'a'},
        {'letter': 'b'},
        {'letter': 'c'}];
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `map`

```
var output = data.map( s => ({letter:s.src}) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
    "src": 'a'
  },
  {
    'src': 'b'
  },
  {
    'src': 'c'
  }
];

console.log(data.map(s => ({
  letter: s.src
})));
```

But if there are multiple other keys and you only want to change `src` from it then

```
var output = data.map( s => {
  if ( s.hasOwnProperty("src") )
  {
     s.letter = s.src;
     delete s.src;   
  }
  return s;
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
    "src": 'a'
  },
  {
    'src': 'b'
  },
  {
    'src2': 'c'
  }
];

var output = data.map(s => {
  if (s.hasOwnProperty("src")) {
    s.letter = s.src;
    delete s.src;
  }
  return s;
})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: How's that the correct one? They all return same result.

Comment: @JohnKennedy Actually I removed my comment. I have mentioned that comment in the context of react. But the OP didn't mentioned anything about react. So I removed my comment. you can the check the link what i am meaning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348171/es6-map-an-array-of-objects-to-return-an-array-of-objects-with-new-keys

Answer (score 7):

Use array.map

```
data.map(function(d) { return { letter: d.src } })
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use `map` method. Check it out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
data.map(function(item) {
    return { letter: item.src };
})
```

Answer (score 3):

With `map` you can achieve what you want. Kindly note that `map` returns a new array and doesn't modify the existing array.

```
data.map((item) => ({ letter: item.src }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newData = data.map(a => { "letter": a.src })
```